# Is it possible to remove an ID where it is not used?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
code VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
warranty TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
producing_country VARCHAR(50),
)
```

Each product in my table has a unique code and This products is also known in stock as this codes

Codes are something like this: (AR-X22 , RF-3654, ...)

My question is can i remove the ID cloumn in this table? Because it has no special application

And does it hurt if I want to use the code column instead of id in join ?

Comment: You could remove it, but I would recommend keeping it. Also there would be no problem using code in a join.

Comment: @Icewine  Why do you recommend I keep the ID column?

Comment: Its good practice to have a table with an id INT AUTO_INCREMENT and PRIMARY KEY . It makes sure each row is unique. If other programmers come and look at your table they will expect to see an id column. Having a VARCHAR as a unique row key is is asking for trouble. There are all sorts of encoding troubles and things that can make strings as identifiers unreliable.[ For example: "ABX-112" and "ABX -112" (space hidden in there)]  If you just dont want to see ID column do like ravioli states below and just make a new view and not show it.

Comment: Don't do this. What if you decide to change the stock code system? It would be a pain to maintain.

Comment: Other than points raised above, ID is int so consumes 4 bytes only; on the other hand code is consuming 30+ bytes. Now you will have this PK as FK in lot of other tables and if you use the varchar as PK, you will be increasing your space consumption significantly

Comment: Also, if you have a continuous increasing value, it is easier to update index tree for that; not so easy for a varchar  , as you will have lot of mid-tree inserts. It gets more heavy when you have multiple tables using it as FK. So, only time having this varchar field as PK is beneficial, when you don't use it as FK in other tables. Also, you ensure that you are entering increasing code values

Comment: @Icewine thanks, Please submit your comment as an answer to me I can confirm your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its good practice to have a table with an id INT AUTO_INCREMENT and PRIMARY KEY.

It makes sure each row is unique. If other programmers come and look at your table they will expect to see an id column.

Having a VARCHAR as a unique row key is is asking for trouble. There are all sorts of encoding troubles and things that can make strings as identifiers unreliable.

For example: "ABX-112" and "ABX -112" (space hidden in there)

If you just don't want to see ID column do like ravioli states below and just make a new view and not show it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your `id` column is specified as your PK, which means it's used to uniquely identify that row in your table.  It looks like it's an identity-type field, which should take care of the uniqueness requirement.

If you want to use `code` as your new "id" field, that should be fine as long as you make sure it's a unique value when you add rows.  It shouldn't have any effect on joins as long as you update your other tables to use the new `code` field.

I don't know how easy it is to fiddle with PK's on a table that already has data.  Your best bet is to create a new table without the `id` field and populate it using the data in your current table.

If it's just a matter of not wanting to see / deal with an `id` field you never use, you can always create a view and exclude that field from being returned.

Comment: I've never used ID

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Products DROP COLUMN id, ADD PRIMARY KEY(id), DROP UNIQUE(code);`

Answer (score -2):

As per my understanding, You want to remove `Id` from the table and want to use `Product code` at that place.

A table relationship is based on the primary and foreign key constraints and it is not necessary that every time you have to Id column as primary key.

> If you have product code and which will always be unique and not null
>   then you can use Code as the primary key for the table rather then
>   unnecessary Id column.

It will also work if you do not create a column wither primary.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are creating Product Code as primary key and also making it index coumn then there is not a performance issue.

Comment: I would not advise anyone to create a table without a primary key. That is a terrible idea

Comment: But I am not saying to create a table without Primary key. I am just saying It is not necessarily the column name should be id It may be anything, and I am just saying table can be created without a primary key, but I also not prefer this.

Comment: "It will also work if you do not create a column wither primary" seems to suggest that OP creates their table without a primary key. If that isn't what you mean then please edit the text to clarify. And if you don't think it's a good idea to do it, then why did you mention it? Just because it's possible doesn't mean you should say it...since this is supposed to be an Answer to the question, then whatever you say here is going to be viewed as advice. If you advise **against** something, then you should make that very clear.